# How to compare objects of two different arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I have a react application and in that I have the following list of objects.

```
const orderItems = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "item 1",
    price: "100",
    availableQty: 2,
    out: ""
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "item 2",
    price: "100",
    availableQty: 2,
    out: ""
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "item 3",
    price: "100",
    availableQty: 2,
    out: ""
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "item 4",
    price: "100",
    availableQty: 2,
    out: ""
  }
];
```

Im mapping through the `orderItems` list and display the name with a `checkbox`. I have a state named `selectedItem` and when the checkbox is checked, new object adds to the `selectedItem` along with the `id` of the `orderItems` as shown in the following code.

```
const handleSelect = (e, item) => {
    const { checked } = e.target;

    const newObj = {
      id: item.id,
      isAdded: true,
      reason: "",
      issue: "",
      availableStock: ""
    };

    if (checked) {
      setselectedItem((previousState) => [...previousState, newObj]);
    }
    if (checked === false) {
      const filteredItems = selectedItem.filter(
        (singleItem) => singleItem.id !== item.id
      );

      setselectedItem(filteredItems);
    }
  };
```

In the react app, Im mapping the `orderItems` and showing the `name` with a checkbox. When the checkbox is checked, I add a new object to `selectedItem` with the `id` of `orderItems` and if the `selectedItem` is empty, I display a as "list is empty". If checkbox is selected, I display a `input` tag under the `name` and if its not selected, i display a `label` with the text "not selected" as shown in the code below.

```
<div className="app">
      {items.map((item) => (
        <div className="issue">
          <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => handleSelect(e, item)} />
          <label>{item.name}</label>
          {selectedItem.length > 0 ? (
            <>
              {selectedItem.map((singleItem) =>
                singleItem.id === item.id ? (
                  <input type="number" />
                ) : (
                  <label>not selected</label>
                )
              )}
            </>
          ) : (
            "list is empty"
          )}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
```

The issue here is, when one item is `checked`, it show `input` tag under selected item and shows "not selected" label under other items but if i select two checkboxes,  both not selected label and input tag displays. If i select 3 checkboxes, not selected label displays two times with input tag.

What i want is to display only the input tags under selected items and display not selected label under unchecked items.

codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/minsaf-2jjt2g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mapping the `selectedItem` array for every element in the `item` array. This means for any element in the array that some condition matches and both the input and label are rendered.

If I understand the code and your expected behavior I think you should conditionally render a single input or label based on if the `selectedItem` array includes an element matching by id.

Example:

```
<div className="app">
  {items.map((item) => (
    <div className="issue">
      <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => handleSelect(e, item)} />
      <label>{item.name}</label>
      {selectedItem.length ? (
        selectedItem.some((singleItem) => singleItem.id === item.id) ? (
          <input type="number" />
        ) : (
          <label>not selected</label>
        )
      ) : (
        "list is empty"
      )}
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

[image: Edit how-to-compare-objects-of-two-different-arrays-in-javascript]